# zero size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, valueerror

Hi I am trying to work out why I am getting this Value Error. I am opening a table I created in Excel and assigning it to an array in Python. I have some satellite imagery that I want to find some statistics for. It is throwing up a value error, and I have checked that the image opens in Python beforehand and it does.

First I am opening the table in python

```
path = "D:\\Iceberg data\\RADARSAT\\"

Table_icebergs_all = pd.read_excel(path+'Image_index_SG_C.xlsx', '20160415')
# the last argument in the function selects the sheet inside the excel file
# HERE IT EXTRACTS THE ICEBERG POSITIONS IN THE TABLE 
dim = Table_icebergs_all.shape



# GETS THE DIMENSION OF THE TABLES
dim_sat = iceberg_sat.shape[0]

# ALLOCATE THE COORDINATES TO NUMPY ARRAYS FOR SATELLITE POINTS
x_sat = np.zeros(dim_sat, dtype = 'int')
y_sat = np.zeros(dim_sat, dtype = 'int')
for i in range(0, dim_sat):
    x_sat[i] = np.round(iceberg_sat['python x'][i])
    y_sat[i] = np.round(iceberg_sat['python y'][i])


# HERE IT EXTRACTS THE CLUTTER POSITION IN THE TABLE 


# cl1 is the upper left corner
# cl2 is the bottom right corner

############# FOR THE SATELLITE IMAGE
cl1_x_sat = np.zeros(dim_sat, dtype = 'int')
cl1_y_sat = np.zeros(dim_sat, dtype = 'int')
cl2_x_sat = np.zeros(dim_sat, dtype = 'int')
cl2_y_sat = np.zeros(dim_sat, dtype = 'int')

for i in range(0, dim_sat):
    cl1_x_sat[i] = np.round(iceberg_sat['py x min'][i])
    cl1_y_sat[i] = np.round(iceberg_sat['py y min'][i])
    cl2_x_sat[i] = np.round(iceberg_sat['py x max'][i])
    cl2_y_sat[i] = np.round(iceberg_sat['py y max'][i])

    
sat = T11_april15 
gnd = gpri_april15


ice_sat_max = np.zeros(dim_sat)
cl_sat_max = np.zeros(dim_sat)
cl_sat_mean = np.zeros(dim_sat)
for i in range(dim_sat):


  ice_sat_max[i] = sat[x_sat[i],y_sat[i]]

  cl_sat_mean[i] = np.mean(sat[cl1_x_sat[i]:cl2_x_sat[i],cl1_y_sat[i]:cl2_y_sat[i]])
  cl_sat_max[i] = np.max(sat[cl1_x_sat[i]:cl2_x_sat[i],cl1_y_sat[i]:cl2_y_sat[i]])

  # we evalute the target to clutter ratio using the mean or the max of the clutter
  TCR_sat_mean = ice_sat_max/cl_sat_mean
  TCR_sat_max  = ice_sat_max/cl_sat_max
```

Here is the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-2483c16a03b9>", line 12, in <module>
    cl_sat_max[i] = np.max(sat[cl1_x_sat[i]:cl2_x_sat[i],cl1_y_sat[i]:cl2_y_sat[i]])

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in amax

  File "C:\Users\job2\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2668, in amax
    keepdims=keepdims, initial=initial, where=where)

  File "C:\Users\job2\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 90, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? It is using the numpy mean and numpy max.

Comment: Check `sat[cl1_x_sat[i]:cl2_x_sat[i],cl1_y_sat[i]:cl2_y_sat[i]]`.  Is the shape 0 in one of the dimensions?

Comment: @hpaulj I have just checked this. It seems that they are showing (98, ) as a size, so I think one of the dimensions is 0.

Comment: `(98,)` is a 1d dimensional shape;  `(98,0)` would be 2d with a 0 dimension.  `sat[a:b, c:d]` is a 2d slice of `sat`, so the shape would have 2 terms.  (The comma in (98,) does not mean there's a missing dimension, or a 0 one.  That's a 1 element tuple.  You may need to brush up on some basic Python.)

Comment: @hpaulj upon further inspection the code for cl_sat_mean[i] is throwing up a 'nan' value on the first data point which is not correct.  The dataframe has no nan values in it, all I'm trying to do is work out the mean and max of my clutter (cl1_x_sat, cl2_x_sat, cl1_y_sat, cl2_y_sat)  columns

Comment: When I do `np.mean(np.ones((0,3)))` I get a `nan`, and a RunTImeWarning.  So it too is having problems with a slice that has a 0 dimension.

Comment: when I find and remove the nan value for the code, the error still remains with the code below it, I am going to get my supervisor to help if I don't manage to solve this. None of my arrays have any nan values on them upon checking. I get a RunTimeWarning if I try np.isnan on the cl_sat_mean. I will try to find the 0 dimension slice.